# How do I get the substring up to the first blank in C#?

Tags: c#, linq2db

I have the following C# linqToDb query:

```
var instruments = (from res in _db.Instrument.Instruments.WithNoLock()
  where Sql.Like(ticker, res.Value.Substring(0, 3))
  select new
  ... etc ...
```

This clearly will do a comparison of ticker to the first 3 characters of res.Value. But instead I want to do the comparison to res.Value up to the first empty space, excluding that empty space. So for instance

```
"VVR" and "VVR UT" would match.
```

I have made various attempts but have failed. How can this be done?

Comment: You've tagged this "linqtodb". Is your Linq query going to be translated into SQL? Is this Entity Framework, and what database are you using?

Comment: ""VVR" and "VVR UT" would match."  -- wouldn't the space between WR and UT be an empty space?

Comment: Will the `StartsWith` method work?

Comment: @gunr2171, [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db) is a library and it is not EF.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer from another angle.

I think you have it backward.

If I read your code right, you look for anything where res.value.substring starts with the ticker.

Do it like that.

```cs
where res.value.StartsWith(ticker)
```

Then filter the results again - for anything that is a false hit, i.e.

AAA as ticker and instrument is AAAAB - that should be a small list.

ALTERNATIVELY:

```cs
where (res.value == ticker || res.Value.StartsWith(ticker + ' '))
```

Both approachs avoid the dynamic substring in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial programming exercise.

- Find the first character that you like as separator.
- Use substring - if you run on an outdated version of .NET. Since some version there are better ways than creating YET ANOTHER STRING.

Alternative - definitely less efficient as it DEFINITLY makes another string:

- Use a regex.

Not a specialist here - if I have to write a regex, I have an AI write it and the test cases.

If your problem is #1, you definitely should do some basic string manipulation exercises.

Comment: Your answer needs code to address the specific question.

Comment: I don't think regex would work as the query is going to be translated to SQL.

Comment: Definitely, but then there isa good question what the heck that is - a list of values in a string instead of proper database design? Not that rare. Just no idea on my side how SqlLite works - i.e. limitations of that particular adapter. Even substring may not work then.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try this :

```
res.Value.Substring(res.Value.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: And that works how when there is no space? Especially - why call substring if it is not a substring?

Comment: The question is how to get the first part of a string from start to the first blank space.
Explained as he did, it should do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, everyone. At first, I thought my issue was with linqToDb somehow, and I am not that familiar with linqToDb. But in fact, it was my misunderstanding of the IndexOf function. This fixed it:

```
where Sql.Like(ticker, res.Value.Substring(0, res.Value.IndexOf(' ') == -1) ? res.Value.Length : res.Value.IndexOf(' ')))
```